# MySQL foreign key failure on create but not alter statement

Tags: mysql

The below SQL fails. with "#1005 - Can't create table 'scheduler_appointmentLog' (errno: 150)"

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `scheduler_appointment` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `timeAdded` INT NOT NULL,
  `timeModified` INT NOT NULL,
  `core_office_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `core_patrparty_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `core_procedure_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `core_staff_id_dr` INT NOT NULL,
  `scheduler_appointmentStatus_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `scheduler_chair_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `apptDate` DATE NULL,
  `startTime` TIME NULL,
  `endTime` TIME NULL,
  `arrivedTime` TIME NULL,
  `seatTime` TIME NULL,
  `readyForDoctor` TIME NULL,
  `frontDeskTime` TIME NULL,
  `departTime` TIME NULL,
  `comment` LONGTEXT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_scheduler_appointment_scheduler_appointmentRequest1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id`)
    REFERENCES `scheduler_appointmentRequest` (`scheduler_appointment_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_scheduler_appointment_financial_payschedQ1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id`)
    REFERENCES `financial_payschedQ` (`scheduler_appointment_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_scheduler_appointment_financial_chargeLog1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id`)
    REFERENCES `financial_chargeLog` (`scheduler_appointment_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_scheduler_appointment_scheduler_appointmentLog1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id`)
    REFERENCES `scheduler_appointmentLog` (`scheduler_appointment_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

HOWEVER if i turn it into 2 statements it works. The Create table in one statement and the constraints in the other.

This will add the table with no errors.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `scheduler_appointment` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `timeAdded` INT NOT NULL,
  `timeModified` INT NOT NULL,
  `core_office_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `core_patrparty_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `core_procedure_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `core_staff_id_dr` INT NOT NULL,
  `scheduler_appointmentStatus_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `scheduler_chair_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `apptDate` DATE NULL,
  `startTime` TIME NULL,
  `endTime` TIME NULL,
  `arrivedTime` TIME NULL,
  `seatTime` TIME NULL,
  `readyForDoctor` TIME NULL,
  `frontDeskTime` TIME NULL,
  `departTime` TIME NULL,
  `comment` LONGTEXT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

And this will add the constraint with no errors.

```
ALTER TABLE `scheduler_appointment` ADD 
  CONSTRAINT `fk_scheduler_appointment_scheduler_appointmentRequest1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id`)
    REFERENCES `scheduler_appointmentRequest` (`scheduler_appointment_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

EDIT...
Working export from phpMyAdmin to show mine is not backwards.

```
ALTER TABLE `scheduler_appointment`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_scheduler_appt_financial_payschedQ1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `financial_payschedQ` (`scheduler_appointment_id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_scheduler_appointment_financial_payschedQ1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `financial_payschedQ` (`scheduler_appointment_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_scheduler_appointment_scheduler_appointmentLog1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `scheduler_appointmentLog` (`scheduler_appointment_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_scheduler_appointment_scheduler_appointmentRequest1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `scheduler_appointmentRequest` (`scheduler_appointment_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

I guess i need help to understand why the ALTER table will add it to the database but it can not be done in the create table statement. If they both failed i would not bother asking, but one works and one doesnt. If MySQL Workbench would export as ALTER statements (like phpMyAdmin does) instead of inline statements then i also wouldn't care to know the answer. However i am stuck needing to know to make the exported file from workbench to load into phpMyAdmin.

Comment: The `ALTER` has 1 FK, the `CREATE` tries to define 3 FKs (all from the `(id)` which seems rather spurious.)

Comment: How come id is a FK for three different tables?!

Comment: @ypercube, that is how MySQL workbench exports it. I guess i can take the export and fix them all by hand? Seems kind of broken for the program to do that if it does not work. I can run all 3 seperate and it works, i just posted the one for the example.

Comment: @mamdouh, three other tables link to the id of this table.

Comment: Can you tell us the primary key of `scheduler_appointmentRequest` table? Is it `(scheduler_appointment_id)`?

Comment: @ypercube, no that is an index in the table. Every table has a PK called "id" for consistancy. All tables that link have a {PARENT_TABLE}_id index field that links back to the parent table.

Comment: Then you probably have your foreign keys messed up. The `REFERENCES scheduler_appointmentRequest (scheduler_appointment_id)` suggests that `(scheduler_appointment_id)` should be either primary or unique key in table `scheduler_appointmentRequest`. Since that is not the case, you probably meant to have `FOREIGN KEY (some_other_column) REFERENCES scheduler_appointmentRequest(id)`

Comment: Or that the Foreign key should be defined (the other way around) in table `scheduler_appointmentRequest`, referencing `scheduler_appointmentLog(id)`

Comment: @ypercube, there was aproblem with that table. However i edited the post with a new table and constraints that is correct. The field names are indexed & the id is primary.

Comment: I see no vital corrections. The FK definitions still look messed up.

Comment: Your `CREATE TABLE scheduler_appointment` statement cannot be fixed, because the three foreign keys in its definition actually belong in three other tables' `CREATE TABLE` statements; they cannot be created as part of `scheduler_appointment`. If those three tables already exist, the only way to add the foreign keys is through `ALTER TABLE` statements, a solution that you have already confirmed to work.

Comment: @ypercube, the links are to keys in other tables. 3 tables looking at the id of this one.

Comment: @lanzz, i can agree with that, but if that is the case why does the workbench output 100% broken code? Would not seem that it would do that which is why i am going with a mistake on my part instead.

Comment: Please read again how foreign key constraints work and how they should be defined. You make two mistakes, you are defining them backwards and placing them in the wrong table.

Comment: @ypercube, When i use the designer tool in phpmyadmin to link them, it gives the same outcome as workbench with the alter statement.

Comment: @AustinBest are you completely certain that the first `CREATE TABLE` statement in your question was produced by MySQL Workbench, exactly the way you have presented it? If you try to export your schema from Workbench again, are you still getting the same `CREATE TABLE` statement?

Comment: Then you are linking them the wrong way. An FK from `A(columnA) REFERENCES B(columnB)` is not the same thing as `B(columnB) REFERENCES A(columnA)`

Comment: @lanzz, yes. I copied and pasted from the output window to here. The top create table. The one without the FK's was one i ran manually by removing the constraints from workbench's.

Comment: @ypercube, based on the documentation >> CONSTRAINT `{FK_NAME}` FOREIGN KEY (`{THIS_TABLE_FIELD}`) REFERENCES `{OTHER_TABLE}` (`{OTHER_FIELD}`) and if you look at mine, that is correct. I am using the id of the current table and the fields from the other tables to point back to it. So if i am doing it wrong, can you post an example i can see of how it is wrong?

Comment: The documentation also says that `{OTHER_TABLE} ({OTHER_FIELD})` should be (although not required) a primary or unique key. Is that true in your definitions?

Comment: Can you export your schema diagram from Workbench as PNG and post it for us to see? You can just post the part showing the `schedule_appointment`, `scheduler_appointmentRequest`, `financial_payschedQ`, `financial_chargeLog` and `scheduler_appointmentLog` tables and their relations.

Comment: @AustinBest I'm saying that your definitions may be syntactically correct (and "work") but they make no sense and would result in more problems sooner or later.

Comment: @ypercube, i have added an edit with the export from phpMyAdmin that shows my constraint is the correct direction (A >> B) as it is the same as mine with the exception of the name its self is different. All "id" fields are PK and all {TABLE}_id fields are not unique or primary because they are log tables, therefor they can not be. It is required for it to be an index, same table type & same field type which they all are.

Comment: No, your constraints are in the wrong direction! The `(OTHER_FIELD)`s are not unique! You have the `{THIS_TABLE_FIELD}` to be primary keys.

Comment: @ypercube, ok bud. I will try to reverse them and see what happens.

Comment: Join [room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46764/foreign-keys)